# Target machine actively refuses mysqli database connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm in the process of implementing a system for database table replication.  I'm aware of the latter MySQL technique but I couldn't get it working.  What I have now is essentially a preliminary implementation.

This is the code I have thus far.

```
//This is where DBHandler is defined
$documentRoot=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once($documentRoot."/Classes/DBHandler.php");

$src_controller = new DBHandler();

$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$temp = $src_controller->select($query);

//Convert temporary database contents into usable result
while($rowObject=mysql_fetch_object($temp)){
    $result[]=$rowObject;
}

//Create database handler to handle database
$dest_controller = new mysqli("ip address", "user", "password", "database name");

if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    $errorMessage = sprintf("'%s'", $mysqli->connect_error);
    echo $errorMessage;
}
else{
    $dest_controller->query("DELETE * FROM table");

    //Processing of data goes here
    foreach($result as $item){
        //Create query to insert individual records
        $start = "INSERT INTO table(field1, field2...) VALUES (";
        $end = sprintf("'%s', %d, %d, %f, %f)", field1, field2...);
        $start .= $end;

        //Database handler uses $start to insert record
        $dest_controller->query($start);
    }

    $dest_controller->close();
}
```

The database being read from is on a different server from the one being written to.  I tried checking the host for the target database with the command "SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname'" and wound up with a site that just gives a "sorry, wrong page or we've moved" page.  What's more is that the port number I see in the URL doesn't match up with what the "SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port'" command gives me.  The latter command says 3306.

I'm not really sure what to do.  We use cPanel X to connect to the database and there's an option to allow select IPs remote access to this database.  I'm positive I granted access to the right addresses but this accomplished nothing.

Is this some kind of issue with the host or did I not use the right IP address for connection when I created the mysqli object?

Comment: just checking; but you want to use the ip address of your MYSQL server in the `new mysqli()` part, not the address of your PHP server.

Comment: I did use the MySQL server address.  I tested this thing and the "target is actively refusing the connection" message is the first result.  Everything that follows is an error related to that, but I can see that the PHP is correct.  I've used the same code in another file that experiences no issues, but the latter is just local writing and deletion.

Comment: If you have set up the cPanel allowing the remote IP access with "Remote MySQL" in the Databases tab then the next step would be to check `WHM` settings (the parent program to CPanel), if you have access to that? But I don't have any more immediate suggestions. 3306 is the/a standard port for MySQL

Comment: another obvious question but have you checked that the user that you're logging in as in `new mysqli()` exists on the MySQL server?

Comment: Yes.  We have two sites, one intended for the public and another meant for management-related operations.  On the public site, there's a class that has the connection information already inserted into the mysqli object it creates to handle everything.  I copied all of that information for this script so there's no reason it should be incorrect.

Comment: On the command line of the web server, have you tried connecting? `mysql -h "ip address" -u "user" -p"password" -D "database name"` (no quotes needed of course, just the values).

Answer (score 0):

If the MySQL port open on that server?  Check with this:

```
telnet yoursever.address.com 3306
```

If telnet doesn't connect, then the port is blocked and you will need your hosting provider to open it up.